# href around input type submit

Tags: html, css, forms, button

why isn't a href around an input type submit not working in IE? (and what can I do to fix it)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
<a href="1.html"><input type="submit" class="button_active" value="1"></a>
<a href="2.html"><input type="submit" class="button" value="2"></a>
<a href="3.html"><input type="submit" class="button" value="3"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* CSS Buttons: http://www.web4site.de/css/css-buttons.php */
.button {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border:none;
    font-size:14px;
    background: url(../img/button.gif) no-repeat center;
    color: #000000;
    height:27px;
    width:134px; 
    font-variant:small-caps;
}

.button:hover {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border:none;
    font-size:14px;
    background: url(../img/button.gif) no-repeat center;
    color: #FF0000;
    height:27px;
    width:134px; 
    text-decoration:none;
    font-variant:small-caps;
}

.button_active {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border:none;
    font-size:14px;
    background: url(../img/button.gif) no-repeat center;
    color: #FF0000;
    height:27px;
    width:134px; 
    font-variant:small-caps;
}
```

This works fine in firefox ...

Comment: you have to accept that html has its limitations

Answer (score 23):

Why would you want to put a submit button inside an anchor?  You are either trying to submit a form or go to a different page.  Which one is it?

Either submit the form:

```
<input type="submit" class="button_active" value="1" />
```

Or go to another page:

```
<input type="button" class="button_active" onclick="location.href='1.html';" />
```

Comment: <input type="button" class="button_active" onclick="location.href='1.html';" />
this one is working fine. Thanks alot :)

Comment: Please use a link to link to a page.

Comment: @Kon what if you wanted to do something like, <a href="?cmd=save">Save</a> But also have it redirect to another page??

Answer (score 12):

It doesn't work because it doesn't make sense (so little sense that HTML 5 explicitly forbids it).

To fix it, decide if you want a link or a submit button and use whichever one you actually want (Hint: You don't have a form, so a submit button is nonsense).

Comment: It makes sense for me, because I need a link and use the input type for formatting it (with and background image etc).

Comment: When you click a link you follow a link. When you click a submit button you submit a form. When you click a submit button inside a link you … simultaneously follow a link and submit a form? Both of which send the browser to a new URI? That makes no sense at all.

Comment: That's your problem. A submit button is a thing for submitting a form, it is not a think for making something look like a button. If you want to make something look like a button **use CSS**.

Comment: I am using CSS for formatting the button :) I do not need the button for submitting a form (therefore no form tag)

Comment: Format the **anchor**, get rid of the button.

Comment: @marc, use a `span` element then instead of `input`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="1.html"><input type="text" class="button_active" value="1"></a>
<a href="2.html"><input type="text" class="button" value="2"></a>
<a href="3.html"><input type="text" class="button" value="3"></a>
```

Try that. Unless you truly need to stick with the type as submit, then what I provided should work. If you are going to stick with submit, then everything mentioned above is correct, it makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Place the link location in the `action=""` of a wrapping `form` tag.

Your first link would be:

```
<form action="1.html">
    <input type="submit" class="button_active" value="1">
</form>
```

Comment: the links are not the same for each input type -.-

Comment: I assuming he wants to submit data for the inputs, so three different forms would be needed

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Quentin. It doesn't make sense as to why you want to do it like that. It's part of the [Semantic Web](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_Web) concept. You have to plan out the objects of your web site for future integration/expansion. Another web app or web site cannot interact with your content if it doesn't follow the proper use-case.

IE and Firefox are two different beasts. There are a lot of things that IE allows that Firefox and other standards-aware browsers reject.

If you're trying to create buttons without actually submitting data then use a combination of DIV/CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can do do it. The input type submit should be inside of a form. Then all you have to do is write the link you want to redirect to inside the action attribute that is inside the form tag.