# Input within link valid html?

Tags: html, forms, internet-explorer

Is this valid markup?

```
<a href="/checkout/booking.php">
   <input type="image" src="/image.gif" value="Complete" title="Complete" style="width: 131px;">
</a>
```

W3C validator doesn't seem to have any problem with it. It works fine in FF and Chrome but nothing happens when you click it in IE.

Comment: check a similar thread out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693566/href-around-input-type-submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML 4 it is valid. In HTML 5 it is invalid. Some browsers have issues with it, so you shouldn't use it even if you are using HTML 4.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is valid in W3C. But its not usual. Putting an input that is actually an image as a link. Maybe consider just using `<img />`