# Buttons not working in IE10

Tags: html, internet-explorer, button

Neither of these are working for me in IE10 at all, but they all work fine in every other browser, including IE9.

## 1) Button within a link

In IE10, this button just literally does nothing when you click it:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/whatever">
    <input type="button" class="btn" value="Edit">
</a>
```

## 2) Submitting a form with a button

```
<form action="myfile.php" method="post">
    <button class="btn btn-large red" id="submit" type="submit">Generate</button>
</form>
```

This has very weird behaviour. Normally you would expect it to go to the `myfile.php` page straight away and start loading. However in this instance, the loader spins on the current file then stops as if it's finished, then 10 seconds later (or however long the form takes to load) it jumps to the next page.

Crucially, from the user's point of view, it looks like it's doing nothing.

Has anyone else come across these issues in IE10?

I've tried various things like setting the x-ua-compatible to:

```
IE=9

IE=9,chrome=1

IE=EmulateIE9
```

etc... but it hasn't made any difference at all.

Comment: IIRC, a button within a link is not valid HTML. If you need a button that acts as a link, just use CSS to style the `<a>` tag to look like a button.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693566/href-around-input-type-submit?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/whatever">Edit</a><br /><br />

<form action="myfile.php" method="post">
    <input class="btn btn-large red" id="submit" type="submit" value="Generate" />
</form>
```