# CSS :checked selector doesn't work

Tags: css

I tried to get a hamburger menu working with only css.

The problem is that my checked function doesn't work as intended and I cant figure out what I got wrong.

The hamburger menu starts at 1000px.

I used input with checkbox to switch between open and close.

```
#toggle:checked + .menu { display: block;}
```

```css
.menu a {
  font-size: 22px;
}

#toggle {
  display: none;
}

.menu {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

#toggle {
  display: block;
}

#toggle:checked+.menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a herf="#">
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
  <div class="menu">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Resources</a>
    <a href="#">Monthly</a>
    <a href="#">Terms</a>
    <a href="#">Privacy</a>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've wrapped these some of these elements in malformed links (`herf`?)....and that's not permitted by HTML

[**See this Q&A**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693566/href-around-input-type-submit)

[image]

The browser seems to be autoclosing the link wrapper just after the `input` which means that the `:checked +` selector fails.

Remove the link or change it to something innocuous, like a div.

```css
nav .menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 0 1% 0 1%;
}

.menu a {
  font-size: 22px;
}

#toggle {
  display: none;
}

.menu {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

nav .menu a {
  display: block;
  color: #2b9dff;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2b9dff;
  margin: 0;
}

#toggle {
  display: block;
}

#toggle:checked+.menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
<div class="menu">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Resources</a>
  <a href="#">Monthly</a>
  <a href="#">Terms</a>
  <a href="#">Privacy</a>
</div>
```