# jquery - post() method gets `not found` error

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to send an email address to my `submit.php` as post and receive a response with jquery.

`submit.php` and `index.html` are in website root and `script.js` is in 'js' folder.

my `index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
<input id="email" type="email" placeholder="  Email"><br>
<a href=""><button id="submit-btn">send</button></a>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my `script.js`:

```js
$(document).ready(()=>{
    $("#submit-btn").click(()=>{
        $.post("../submit.php", { user_email: $("#email").val()})
            .done((data)=>{
                alert(data);
            })
            .fail((xhr, status, error)=>{
                alert(error);
            });
    });
});
```

my `submit.php`:

```php
<?php
$email = (isset($_POST['user_email']) ? $_POST['user_email'] : "nothing");
echo $email;
```

I expect the output to be my email address, but the actual output is `not found`.
I think my request has failed

Comment: Are your index.html and post.php in the same folder? I'm asking because of the `../` in front of the filename. You also should considering to check the network-tab and compare the url of the post-request yo your file structure.

Comment: @Jan yes, `indes.html` and `submit.php` are in the same folder

Comment: Can you reach the submit.php with your browser if you try to access it directly. It could be that there are some modrewrite/.htaccess or similar in action.

Comment: @Jan yes i can reach `submit.php` with `http://localhost:8080/sajjad/submit.php`

Comment: @hamed Also take a look at [href around input type submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693566/href-around-input-type-submit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say that both files are in the same folder, there is no need for the `../` in front of your request.

```
$.post("../submit.php", { user_email: $("#email").val()})
```

```
$.post("submit.php", { user_email: $("#email").val()})
```